# How to add all list student items in file using interface?

Tags: c#, .net

Hello I'm trying to add a list in a file using interface, but I can add only last item of list in it? Whats wrong?

I think I'm ok with interface.

```
//interface
interface IRuajtshem
    {
      void Ruaj();
    }
```

I think here is the problem.

```
 //class
        public class Student : IRuajtshem
    {
        protected int ID;
        protected string emri;
        protected string mbiemri;

        ...
        ...
        ...

        public void Ruaj()
        {
            string path = @"C:\\...\\...\\text.txt";
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Delete(path);
            }
            else if (!File.Exists(path))
                File.Create(path).Close();
            var f = File.AppendText(path);
            f.WriteLine(Studenti + " " + Studentii + " " + Studentiii);
            f.Close();
        }
    }
```

And finally the list ...

```
//@Main()
List<Student> student = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student(1, "Name", "Surname"),
                new Student(2, "name", "Surname"),
                new Student(3, "Name", "surname"),
                new Student(4, "name", "surname")
            };

            foreach (Student st in student)
            {
                st.Ruaj();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Comment: What are these variables _Studenti, Studentii, Studentiii_ ? Do you have defined them somewhere?

Comment: Are get, set for ID, name and surname for each student.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary No, `student` is just a bad name for `List<Student>`

Comment: omg. sorry. my mistake! @SimpleVar

Comment: your logic have issue.. First time file is created.. second time deleted... third time crested.. fourth time deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep deleting and recreating the file. Try this instead:

```
public void Ruaj()
{
    string path = @"C:\\...\\...\\text.txt";
    using (var f = File.AppendText(path))
    {
        f.WriteLine(Studenti + " " + Studentii + " " + Studentiii);
    }
}
```

This is the part of your code that kept "resetting" the file:

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path); // deletes file if it exists
}
else if (!File.Exists(path))
    File.Create(path).Close(); // creates empty file if doesnt exist
```

And I think that creating an empty file is unneeded as well, because AppendText will create the file for you if it doesn't exist, and not throw an error:

> Creates a StreamWriter that appends UTF-8 encoded text to an existing file, or to a new file if the specified file does not exist.

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Another method you might want to check out is [`AppendAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which gets a path and a string, and does all the dirty work for you in one line. Just need to make sure your string ends with "\r\n" if you ever want a line break.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are deleting the file if it exists:

```
if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Delete(path);
            }
```

You should open the file instead of deleting it.